# JavaScript counting objects to find correct price and add to column

Tags: javascript

I'm scraping data from TMview.org. i need to calculate a price with some of the information i scrape.
the output is .Xls i use a chrome extension to scrape and run a Javascript thru the output to clean up the data.

**E.G**

The data is in Column 12 of my output `this.values[13]`

3,6,9,12,14,16,18,14, (40.000)

3,5, (10.000)

i thought about appending " , " to the string and the counting the " , "
for a price = 10x " , " = 50.000

the price needs to be added in Column 11`this.values[12] = this.values[12];` is how i target the column in Javascript

But how to count " , " in `this.values[13]` is beyond my knowledge

Answer (score 0):

if this.values[13] is a Javascript string then you can do this

```
this.values[13].split(',').length
```

This will give you number of elements separated by comma, number of commas would be 1 less then above number.

Answer (score 0):

The number of commas should one less of total length if we use split because it's return an array that contain total number of elements that separated by comma. Example:

```js
var val="3,6,9,12,14,16,18,14,";// this is your value like this.values[13]

console.log(val.split(',').length-1);
```